# How can I reset the List(of String) in my structure but not reset the values in the previous structure element in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I have multiple menu items. Each menu item has multiple fields. I'm trying to add all field values the AllFields variable for each item, but I keep getting values from the previous item(s) (example: the first item has 12 field values (which are different for each item), and the next has those values and 12 more).

I'm trying to reset the AllFields so that each item has only its own 12 values.

Here is my structure:

```
Public Structure MenuItems

    Dim Caption As String
    Dim Category As String
    Dim AllFields As List(Of String)
    Dim CategoryColor As String
End Structure

Dim ExcelMenuItem As New List(Of MenuItems) ' This is a global variable

Public Sub ExcelXMLInput()
    Dim EachMenuItem As New MenuItems()

    for Loop

    EachMenuItem.AllFields.Add(trimItem) ' This is how I add the values to the structure     variable "AllFields"

    ExcelMenuItem.Add(EachMenuItem) ' This is how I add all variables to one structure element

End Sub
```

I tried to use `clear`, but it cleared all values in "AllFields" in all structure elements.

Comment: Looks like you never clear the list?

Comment: It seems like a Class would be a better fit than a Structure here